# What is the smallest flaw that can be detected by ultrasonic technology?

Tags: ultrasound

Ultrasonic transducer is used to detect flaws. What is the smallest flaw that can be detected by ultrasonic technology? One thing I know is that higher the frequency, higher is the sensitivity of the transducer i.e. smaller is the size of the flaw it can detect.

Comment: Depends on the material for one thing.  In theory, one could detect any flaw by looking at phase mismatch of the returns (only weakly depends on wavelength), for another.